# Customize Launch Behavior Choice Options

Tags: client-side-rendering, promoted-links, customization, launch

In SharePoint 2016 Promoted Links in Launch Behavior column I wanted only 'page navigation' and 'New tab' options. So I removed the 'Dialog' option from choice. After this I added items in the Promoted Links. Now in Tiles View when I click on the items with launch behavior 'New tab', those links are always opened in 'Dialog'. Please guide me fix the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

At place of removing "Dialog" choice from column setting, I removed this option from "Launch Behavior" drop down using below jQuery code-

$("select[id*='LaunchBehavior'] option[value='Dialog']").remove();